# Too many database connection slowing website

Tags: mysql, magento

Magento is creating large number of database connection that slow down website.Mysql show full processlist giving below query.

No of connections 1000;
command : creating sort index;
Running query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`name`,`url_rewrite`.`request_path`
FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite`
    ON url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id 
    AND url_rewrite.is_system=1 
    AND url_rewrite.product_id IS NULL AND url_rewrite.store_id='1' AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%' WHERE (main_table.entity_id IN ('761', '1370', '1373'))
    AND (main_table.is_active = '1') 
ORDER BY `main_table`.`path` ASC
```

Comment: Generally: there's loads of advice out there for speeding up a Magento install. I'd start by Googling `magento too many database connections slow` or `magento speed up`. If the query you quote is something specific, maybe it's on topic on http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Same query gets triggered creating more than 1000 connections and leading to 100% cpu and site goes down for 15-20 minutes.